# SharePoint Designer 2010 - Current and Pending list values in Workflow Email

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, approval-process

I'm building a custom workflow in SPD 2010 and I need to create an approval workflow to send designated users an email when the list is updated. The email will need to include the current list field value (current approved value) and the new pending value so the individuals approving the workflow to view the current value and the proposed changes.

Is this possible in SPD 2010, and if so, how do I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

You can create an additional column or columns to capture initial settings. The workflow should fire on item creation and copy the original items you want to track.  On change you do comparisons or read in original data (use the substring actions) in variables and use them as required.

If you need to capture more than a few text strings, you could create a duplicate list and copy the data with a reference ID tied to original item.   This can get a little tricky but will separate your "tracking" data from your live data.